# Selection option list not getting updated when the object value changes

Tags: angular

I'm trying to update the dropdown list when a file is uploaded. In the console I can see the object data being displayed. But its not updating the dropdown list. I'm using `formControlName` attribute to bind the object data.

**HTML**

```
<select formControlName="fileInfoObj" class="form-control" disabled>
  <option *ngFor="let worksheet of fileInfoObj.worksheets" value="worksheet.name">{{worksheet.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
    private fileInfoObj: Object = {};
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.devRequestService.getListOfAgencies().subscribe((data) => {
       ...
       this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers:any)=>  {
            console.log(response);
            return this.fileInfoObj = response;
          };
      });
    }
```

**Object**

```
    {
      "key": "[key]",
      "worksheets": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "name": "default",
          "columns": [
            {
              "index": 0,
              "name": "col-1"
            },
            {
              "index": 1,
              "name": "col-2"
            },
            {
              "index": 2,
              "name": "col-3"
            },
            {
              "index": 3,
              "name": "col-4"
            },
            ...
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to parse the JSON response to object in order to make it work.

```
this.fileInfoObj = JSON.parse(response);
```

And remove `formControlName` from html:

```
formControlName="fileInfoObj"
```